# How to eager load an association only if the type of the record is 'employee'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Person` with a field called `type`, only Persons with `type == employee` belongs to a manager

Person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Employee.rb

```
class Employee < Person
    belongs_to :manager
end
```

Manager.rb

```
class Manager < Person
    has_many :employees
end
```

in the index action of persons_controller i show all persons, but i need to `eager load` manager `if type == 'employee'`

I want something like this :

```
Person.all.includes(:manager if type == 'employee')
```

there is a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since `Manager` and `Employee` are both subclasses of `Person`, when you do `Person.all` you are by definition including all managers.

That said, you can eager load the associated managers by simply using:

Person.includes(:manager)

since `manager_id` will be `nil` for any `Person` entries that aren't employees.\

Similarly, if you make `Manager` a subclass of `Employee`, then there is no need to eager load in the case of `Employee.all`, since all managers will already be included. However, as with the above, you can do:

```
Employee.includes(:manager)
```

Comment: what about if i want to do something like a manager is a subclass of employee... because an manager is an employee its self, and there is a normal employee and a manager, i have a request when i fetch just employees, and i need to eager load their manager if exist, do you know how i can implement this please

Comment: @medBo It should not matter how the models are structured, so long as the `Employee` class has an association with `Manager`, such as your `belongs_to` relationship. So Peter's answer should still work.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin thank you for the answer you are awesome, but i did some changes see my update answer marked as **update** do you have an idea ?

Comment: @medBo With all due respect, I think your update represents a separate question. I would recommend rolling back your edit, deciding what action to take on this answer (i.e. upvote, accept, both, neither) and then posting your new question separately. I will say, however, that there are multiple problems with your new code.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin okey done :-)  i will post this question separately as you say, so i don't know why you say that there are multiple problems with my new code ^^ sometimes we need to do something outside standard to resolve some problems or for performance issue, i I'd love to know what do you thing about it, it will help me more